# Ordenar array alfabeticamente e mostrar apenas primeiro nome de cada item

Tags: java, array

Sou totalmente leigo em Java, queria ajuda para finalizar um exercício.

O enunciado é esse:

> *"escreva um programa que receba um array com o nome
>   completo de 10 pessoas e apresente um array com apenas o primeiro nome
>   de cada pessoa e neste array de apenas nomes os mesmos devem estar
>   listados em ordem alfabética."*
>
> *Exemplo: Joao da Silva, Felipe Santos, Adriano Kramer.... (primeiro
>   array) . Resultado: Adriano, Felipe , Joao ...(segundo array).*
>
> *Assuma apenas o primeiro nome antes do espaço como primeiro nome!*

Já consegui fazer a parte de escrever os dez nomes (coloquei 3 no código pra agilizar nos testes, depois mudo pra 10).

Estou com muitas dificuldades para terminar a parte que mostre apenas o primeiro nome. O professor falou que poderia usar o comando `split()`, mesmo assim não consegui fazer esta parte do exercício.

Segue o meu código:

```
package exercicio2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ListaNomes {

    public static void main(String[] args ) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome[] = new String[3];

        for(int i = 0; i<nome.length; ++i) {

        System.out.print("Digite o nome do " +(i+1) + "º aluno: ");
        nome[i] = input.nextLine();

        }

    System.out.println(" ");

    Arrays.sort(nome);

    for (int i=0; i< nome.length; i++){

        System.out.print(nome[i]+"\n");         
    }

    input.close();

    }       
}
```

Comment: Entre o nome e sobrenome sempre terá apenas um espaço?

Comment: Sim, terá apenas um espaço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome[] = new String[3];

    for(int i = 0; i<nome.length; ++i) {

    System.out.print("Digite o nome do " +(i+1) + "º aluno: ");
    nome[i] = input.nextLine();

    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    Arrays.sort(nome);

    String[] firstNames = new String[nome.length];

    for (int i=0; i< nome.length; i++){

        firstNames[i] = nome[i].split("\\s")[0];         
    }

    for(String firstName : firstNames){
        System.out.println(firstName);
    }
}
```

O [**`split`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) quebra a `String` em um novo array de string, com o nome e sobrenome(que são os valores separados pelo espaço).  O primeiro indice deste array é o nome.

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/kRK9iF).

Nada te impede de exibir os nomes direto no primeiro laço, mas como o exercicio exige um novo array só com nomes, eu fiz o primeiro para separar e armazenar os nomes, e o segundo para exibi-los.

Comment: Só para comentar sobre a regex. `\s` significa qualquer espaço em branco (espaço ou `\t\n\x0B\f\r`). Se você espera que mais que um espaço apareça entre o nome e sobrenome é possível usar `\s+` que significa um ou mais espaços.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Verdade. Eu foquei apenas no enunciado do exercício, que cita um espaço como separador. Mas em outra ocasião, eu verificaria espaços até no começo do nome, já que é uma entrada de usuário.

Comment: @Fumero que erro? Clica no link do IDEONE e executa, está funcionando normalemnte. Qualquer coisa, pode copiar de lá, eu só adicionei o trecho acima no seu código.

Comment: @Fumero deu certo ai?

Comment: Olá amigo, consegui ver onde estava errado, só que na hora de testar o programa e imprimir os nomes fica aparecendo null na lista dos primeiros nomes, como faço para corrigir isso?

Comment: @Fumero o seu código ou o do link?

Comment: @diegofm o meu código.

Comment: Testei com seu código e tambem fica aparecendo null

Comment: @Fumero você executou o código no link do IDEONE? Lá não é exibido null. Veja se você não alterou alguma coisa ai no código que afetou isso.

Comment: Unica coisa que coloquei foi o nome do pacote já que estou usando o eclipse

Comment: @Fumero poste seu código como está agora(exibindo esse null) ou no ideone ou no pastebin e cola o link aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Aqui está o codigo do Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/4dmYiM7h

Comment: Aqui o resultado final: Digite o nome do 1º aluno: Marcelo Augusto
Digite o nome do 2º aluno: Renan Alves
Digite o nome do 3º aluno: Monica Carvalho
 
Marcelo
null
null
Marcelo
Monica
null
Marcelo
Monica
Renan

Comment: @Fumero você havia colocado o terceiro laço dentro do segundo, quando são laços independentes(o segundo remove o sobrenome e popula o array de nomes, o terceiro só exibe este array), o correto é assim: http://pastebin.com/56yDP0p7

Comment: Cara nem me atentei para posição errada da chave que fecha o segundo laço. Valeu mesmo chapa, ajudou muito nesse exercício, bati muito a cabeça com ele. Abraço.